# Overwrite default dropdown (select) style on mobile

Tags: android, html, css

How can I overwrite the default css of a select element on my mobile? When I look at the mobile view in Chrome the style is different than how it actually looks on my mobile (galaxy s6). How can I overwrite it?

How it looks in my browser:

[image]

How it looks on my mobile (added gradient and thicker border):
[image]

Comment: give style in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

To remove default styles you need to write on you styles and use **! important** to over write default style.

eg:- **margin : 0 ! important;**

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 Media Queries, here's an example for a device with max width 480px

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    select {
        //your style goes here 
    }
}
```