# How to fix HTML form select element for mobile preview

Tags: html, forms, html-select

[image]

Has anyone ever seen this? I'm using Visual Studio code and when I preview it in the Brave Browser (devtools exactly similar to Google Chrome browser) the list of options appear away from the layout. Not sure how to explain this better.

No CSS is used it's just the default of the browser. Is there a specific css value I need to change? I just copied the code exact from the w3school https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select

Comment: see possibly [Overwrite default dropdown (select) style on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761717/overwrite-default-dropdown-select-style-on-mobile)

Comment: How is the selection dropdown positioned? If it's transformed into place (or you use some kind of hack to place it) it can sometimes have this kind of effect.

Comment: @SamSpade no css used. It only looks like that when inspecting the element and switch to mobile layout.

Comment: Could you post the html surrounding the element in question? The select element should, itself, work perfectly fine. It's almost certainly something about the code around it that is causing issues.